# Split Last Name and First Name using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column with values like:

```
Full Name
----------------
X-y, z C
CLOSE, Test G.
CMN, DEV S.
Micheal Land
```

I need the output in the following way

```
Last_Name   First_Name  Middle-Name
-----------------------------------
X-y            Z              C
CLOSE          Test           G
CMN            DEV            S
```

Micheal Land

Comment: what is the logic to split?

Comment: Do you really need all of the output on a single line? Have you tried anything? Searched for anything?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not looking for a single line code..
Try this..

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52959/3)

```
 declare @x varchar(20) ='x-yDFGD, DFGDFA GDDb'
    ,@lastname varchar(20),
    @FirstName varchar(20),
    @middleName varchar(20)

    if  charindex(',',@x) >0
    begin
        set @lastname =left(@x, charindex(',',@x)-1) 
        set @x =Ltrim(Rtrim(substring(@x,charindex(',',@x)+1, len(@x))))
        Set @firstName =left(@x, charindex(' ',@x)-1) 
        SET @middleName =substring (@x, charindex(' ',@x) +1,LEN(@X))
        select @lastname as [LastName], @firstName as [FirstName], @middleName as [MiddleName]
    end 
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        set @lastname =left(@x, charindex(' ',@x)-1) 
        SET @firstName =substring (@x, charindex(' ',@x) +1,LEN(@X))
        select @lastname as [LastName], @firstName As [FirstName]
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Create table #temp ([Full Name] varchar(100))

insert into #temp
select 'X-y, z C'
union all 
select 'CLOSE, Test G.'
Union all
select 'CMN, DEV S.'
union all
select 'Micheal Land'
UPDATE #temp SET [Full Name]=REPLACE([Full Name],', ',',')
select  substring([Full Name],0,CASE CHARINDEX(',',[Full Name]) WHEN 0 THEN LEN([Full Name]) ELSE CHARINDEX(',',[Full Name])  END ) Last_Name,
CASE CHARINDEX(',',[Full Name]) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE substring([Full Name],CHARINDEX(',',[Full Name])+1,-CHARINDEX(',',[Full Name])+CHARINDEX(' ',[Full Name])) END First_Name,
CASE CHARINDEX(',',[Full Name]) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE substring([Full Name],CHARINDEX(' ',[Full Name])+1,LEN([Full Name])) END [Middle-Name] from #temp
```